# Apache Cassandra 3.11.6: clustering key error, Undefined column name in table after cass-stress write

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, cassandra-stress

I am currently experiencing an issue where I try to SELECT or INSERT specific column data from cassandra and keep getting an undefined column name error, despite the fact that the column name is a clustering key when looking at the table. However, other columns behave normally.

```
keyspace_name | table_name | column_name | clustering_order | column_name_bytes | kind          | position | type
---------------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------+------
    keyspace1 |  standard1 |          C0 |             none |            0x4330 |        static |       -1 | blob
    keyspace1 |  standard1 |     column1 |              asc |  0x636f6c756d6e31 |    clustering |        0 | text
    keyspace1 |  standard1 |         key |             none |          0x6b6579 | partition_key |        0 | blob
    keyspace1 |  standard1 |       value |             none |      0x76616c7565 |       regular |       -1 | blob

cqlsh> SELECT  "column1" from keyspace1.standard1;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined column name column1"

cqlsh> SELECT  "C0" from keyspace1.standard1;

 C0
------------------------
 0xdc9e1bf05eab897f470a
 0x5ff08459ccd892a25f91
 0x85182fdfe7f86306cd58
 0x10f1dd6febff8cbcf3ad
 0xb8e05320cd1037d6e317
```

Additionally, when inserting data, despite column1 being "undefined," it is still required as a clustering key

```
cqlsh> insert into keyspace1.standard1 (key) VALUES (0xcccc) ;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some clustering keys are missing: column1"
```

when inserting data into other columns however, behavior is normal

```
cqlsh> insert into keyspace1.standard1 (key, "C0") VALUES (0xcccc, 0xbbbb) ;  
cqlsh> SELECT  "C0" from keyspace1.standard1;

 C0                      key
 ----------------------- ------------------------
 0xdc9e1bf05eab897f470a 0x37373539364d4f323330
                 0xbbbb                 0xcccc
 0x5ff08459ccd892a25f91 0x4f503030314c35393330
 0x85182fdfe7f86306cd58 0x30503337373039503231
 0x10f1dd6febff8cbcf3ad 0x394e35344e4b34383631
 0xb8e05320cd1037d6e317 0x4f384c4b37394c4f3631
```

This is after I have run cassandra-stress, and I have run similar tests in 3.11.4 and it worked fine, but when queried the column1 (clustering key) entries were all null, which is something I did not think was possible.

Is this intended behavior that changed from 3.11.4 onwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are dealing with a compact storage table.

You can verify this in cqlsh:

```
describe table keyspace1.standard1;
```

If you see `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` then you have a compact storage table.

Once you drop the compact storage format from this table, you should be able to select the column `column1`.

To drop compact storage:

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace1.standard1 DROP COMPACT STORAGE;
```

I am not sure how you ended up with your table definition (unless cassandra-stress created it for you). The column `column1` is normally found in tables that have been migrated from compact storage.

Normally the following happens when migrating the storage format (for tables that have no clustering column):

- Two new columns column1 text and value blob are added. These columns contain any data written outside the CQL table schema to the Thrift table.
- column1 becomes a clustering column.
- All regular columns become static columns.

More information can be found here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/dropCompactStorage.html